# MDB error running python script to extract CSV to mssql

Tags: python, csv

I am new to Python, I am trying to loop though very large CSV file (4 GB) and put that into MSSQL server. Current SQL tools don't seem to help!

Attached is my script. I am getting below error while running it. Any help would be appreciated.

MSSQL database exit. Login and password is correct. I have also installed pymssql module for windows

E:\Python27>python -x parsedata_mssql.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parsedata_mssql.py", line 28, in 
    except mdb.Error, e:
NameError: name 'mdb' is not defined

Below is my code:

```
           #! /usr/bin/python

          import csv
          import sys
          import _mssql

          fields = [
          (0, 'name'),
          (1, 'street'),
          (2, 'city'),
          (3, 'state'),
          (4, 'zip'),
          (5, 'u1'),
          (6, 'u2'),
          (7, 'phone1'),
          (8, 'phone2'),
          (9, 'contactname'),
          (10, 'relationship'),
          (11, 'gender'),
          (12, 'u3'),
          (13, 'u4'),
          (14, 'industry'),
  ]

         try:
dbconn = _mssql.connect(server='localhost\SQLEXPRESS', user='sa',
        password='password', database='2007usdata')
        except mdb.Error, e:
           print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
          sys.exit(1)

   with open('2007usdata.csv', 'rb') as infile:
reader = csv.reader(infile)
count = 0
for line in reader:
    print "\n\nProcessing\n"
    print line
    if line:
        column_names = ','.join([name for (id, name) in fields])
        value_placeholders = (len(fields) - 1) * '%s, ' + '%s'
        query = "INSERT INTO info(%s) VALUES(%s)" % (column_names, value_placeholders)
        try:
            dbconn.execute_non_query(query, line)
            count += 1
            dbconn.commit()
        except mdb.Error, e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
            sys.exit(1)
   dbconn.close()

   print "\n\nDone: processed %d lines" % (count)
```

Comment: Should `mdb` in your code be `_mssql` maybe?  Where did you get the `mdb.Error` from?  You didn't import any modules named `mdb`, or define it anywhere.

Comment: What error do you get when you use "current SQL tools"?